# Is there any deep connection between algebraic topology and homological algebra on rings?

Tags: commutative-algebra, algebraic-topology, soft-question, ring-theory, homological-algebra

There is a deep connection between algebraic topology and homological algebra on groups.
A group $G$ can be interpreted as the fundamental group of a covering space $Y \rightarrow X$.
(Co)Homology groups of $G$ can be interpreted as those of $X$.
Similarly there is a deep connection between algebraic topology of Lie groups and homological algebra on Lie algebras.
So a natural question is:
Is there any deep connection between algebraic topology and homological algebra on rings?

**EDIT**
I mean by "homological algebra on rings" homological algebra over the abelian categories of modules over rings.

Comment: Please leave a comment for the downvote so that I can improve my question.

Comment: I think that you are perhaps looking for K-theory: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_K-theory, or at least this in the vein of what you're saying. Do you perhaps mean something related to homological dimension of rings though?

Comment: @AlexYoucis I have no idea. That's why I asked.
I know almost nothing about K-theory.
I read the Wikipedia article, but I'm afraid I don't see a deep connection between them.

Comment: Perhaps the first appearance of rings in algebraic topology is that cohomology groups actually assemble into a graded ring.  But of course there are many appearances beyond this.  What do you mean by "homological algebra on rings", though, anyways?  Rings don't form an abelian category.

Comment: Anyways, modern algebraic topology concerns itself considerably with *$E_\infty$-rings*, which are a vast generalization of the ordinary notion of a ring.  In fact, any one of these gives rise to an "extraordinary cohomology theory" (with lots of extra structure).  And the "homological algebra" that one can do with rings -- e.g., Andre-Quillen cohomology -- can be ported over to this setting.  This makes many natural appearances in algebraic topology, too.

Comment: @AaronMazel-Gee Please see my **EDIT** in the question.

Comment: Okay.  The only answer I can think of that $R$-modules would come up explicitly is that the homotopy category of $HR$-module *spectra* should be the derived category of $R$-modules.  (In your other examples, the algebraic objects you're asking about arise geometrically somehow, and the only way I can see for a ring to arise geometrically is for it to *be* the space of interest.)  Incidentally, how does the (group?) co/homology of $G$ show up in a covering space for which it's the group of deck transformations?

Comment: @AaronMazel-Gee "Incidentally, how does the (group?) co/homology of G show up in a covering space for which it's the group of deck transformations?"
I'm not 100% sure but it goes like as follows.
Let $Y$ be an acyclic connected $CW$ space.
Suppose a discrete group $G$ acts properly on $Y$.
Let $X = Y/G$.
Then $H^n(X, \mathbb{Z})$ is isomorphic to $H^n(G, \mathbb{Z})$ for all $n$.

Comment: Ah.  So really this is just when $Y=EG$ and $X=BG$.  Then yes, this computation is actually just a recognition of the bar complex for $BG$ as also giving the appropriate (co)chain complex with which to compute the group (co)homology of $G$.  You can even take this as a *definition* of group (co)homology, if you like.

Comment: I really don't understand why anyone would downvote this question......

Answer (score 5):

Ring theory is always lurking more or less visible in algebraic topology. As your question is quite broad, I'll try and give a quick overview with a few references. Since homological algebra takes place often over R-modules or it can be reduced to this case somehow, it might be a bit difficult to define what you mean by "homological algebra on rings". Nonetheless, here are a few examples that I think fit your description:

- The Hochschild homology of an $R-R$-bimodule reflects some ring-theoretic stuff. For instance, $H_1(R,R)$ of a $k$-algebra $R$ is the module of differentials $\Omega_{R/k}$. If $\mathbb{Q}\subseteq R$ then there is an algebraic decomposition of this homology that is analogous to the Hodge decomposition in complex manifold theory.
- Taking the above example further if $k$ is a ring and $X$ a simplicial set, the cyclic homology (Hochschild homology taking into account a cyclic action on the corresponding simplicial set) of the simplicial module $k[X]$ is the same as the $S^1$-equivariant homology of the geometric realisation of $X$ with coefficients in $k$.

(Hochschild and cyclic homology are related to $K$-theory and the Lie algebra of matrix algebras as well. For the above examples, see Chapter 9 of Weibel's book "An Introduction to Homological Algebra" and all of Loday's book "Cyclic Homology")

- As mentioned in the comments, $K$-theory is like homology on rings. Moreover, algebraic topology is clearly interested in vector bundles; on a nice space $X$ the category of rank $n$ real vector bundles on $X$ is equivalent to the category of rank $n$ finitely generated projective modules over the continuous functions $C(X,\mathbb{R})$. The group $K_0(C(X))$ is the Grothendieck group of the isomorphism classes of fg projectives.
- $K$-theory of course has its roots and many applications to algebraic topology and algebraic geometry. Plentiful examples can be found in "The Handbook of $K$-Theory" (http://www.math.uiuc.edu/K-theory/handbook/)

(In fact, the higher $K$-groups of a ring $R$ can be defined as the homotopy groups of a certain simplicial resolution associated to $R$; simplicial resolutions are like chain complexes in an abelian category, and in fact for abelian categories nonnegative chain complexes and simplicial sets coincide. So it really is like a homology of rings, as opposed to doing abelian homological algebra in the category of modules.)